# GUI running really slow JAVA

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jpanel, listener

So i'm making a little game again for a school project with 2 of my friends.
We have this same idea as before, but now its all graphical (JPanel, JLabel etc. etc.).
We have the basic GUI, but its running really slow. 
When i hit the arrow key, it responds in like 1-2 seconds, and if i hit the fast in a row, it might take up to 15+ seconds.
Here's the code:

Main

```
package game;

import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Gui extends JFrame{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
int n = 0;
int m = 0;
static MapMake mapMake = new MapMake();
static MapRefresh mapRefresh = new MapRefresh();
static JPanel panel = new JPanel();
static Fighting fighting = null;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Gui frame = new Gui();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setTitle("Dungeons and Dragons(and some food)");
    frame.setSize(1280, 720);

    mapMake.setDiscovered(0, 0, 1);
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(10, 10, 2, 2));
    mapRefresh.MapRefresh();
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.addKeyListener(new Listener());
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

MapMake

```
package game;

public class MapMake{
static int[][] discovered = new int[10][10];
static int[][] content = new int[10][10];
static int heroX = 0;
static int heroY = 0;
public void MapMake(){
    discovered[0][0] = 1;
    for (int row = 0; row < 10; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < 10; col++) {
            discovered[row][col] = 0;
        }
    }
    discovered[0][0] = 1;
    int dragon1 = 3;
    int dragon2 = 5;
    int dragon3 = 7;
    int dragon4 = 9;
    int dragon5 = 1;
    int food = 25; // id 6

    while (dragon1 != 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                int x = (int) (Math.random() * 2);
                if (x != 1 && dragon1 != 0 && content[i][j] == 0
                        && (i > 0 && i < 3 || j > 0 && j < 3)) {
                    dragon1--;
                    content[i][j] = 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    while (dragon2 != 0 && food != 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                int x = (int) (Math.random() * 2);
                if (x != 1 && dragon2 != 0 && content[i][j] == 0
                        && (i > 2 && i < 5 || j > 3 && j < 5)) {
                    dragon2--;
                    content[i][j] = 2;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    while (dragon3 != 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
                int x = (int) (Math.random() * 2);
                if (x != 1 && dragon3 != 0 && content[i][j] == 0
                        && (i > 4 && i < 7 || j > 4 && j < 7)) {
                    dragon3--;
                    content[i][j] = 3;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    while (dragon4 != 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
                int x = (int) (Math.random() * 2);
                if (x != 1 && dragon4 != 0 && content[i][j] == 0
                        && (i > 6 && i < 9 || j > 6 && j < 9)) {
                    dragon4--;
                    content[i][j] = 4;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    while (dragon5 != 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                int x = (int) (Math.random() * 2);
                if (x != 1 && dragon5 != 0 && content[i][j] == 0
                        && (i > 8 && i < 10 || j > 8 && j < 10)) {
                    dragon5--;
                    content[i][j] = 5;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    while (food != 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                int x = (int) (Math.random() * 2);
                if (x != 1 && food != 0 && content[i][j] == 0) {
                    food--;
                    content[i][j] = 6;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    discovered[0][0] = 1;
}
public int getDiscovered(int i, int j) {
    return discovered[i][j];
}
public int getContent(int i, int j) {
    return content[i][j];
}
public int getHeroX() {
    return heroX;
}
public int getHeroY() {
    return heroY;
}
public void setDiscovered(int i, int j, int k) {
    MapMake.discovered[i][j] = k;
}
public void setContent(int i, int j, int k) {
    MapMake.content[i][j] = k;
}
public void setHeroX(int heroX) {
    this.heroX = heroX;
}
public void setHeroY(int heroY) {
    this.heroY = heroY;
}
}
```

MapRefresh

```
package game;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MapRefresh extends Gui{
static MapMake mapMake = Gui.mapMake;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public void MapRefresh() {
    BufferedImage hall = null;
    BufferedImage valge = null;
    JPanel panel = Gui.panel;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            //              panel.add(new JButton("" + content[i][j]));
            if (mapMake.getDiscovered(i, j) == 1) {
                panel.add(new JLabel("hero on siin peal"));
            } else if (mapMake.getDiscovered(i, j) == 0) {
                try {
                    panel.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(hall = ImageIO.read(new File("C:/hall.jpg")))));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                } catch (NullPointerException e){

                }
            } else {
                try {
                    panel.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(valge = ImageIO.read(new File("C:/valge.jpg")))));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                } catch (NullPointerException e){

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

and Listener

```
package game;

import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Listener extends Gui implements KeyListener{
static MapRefresh mapRefresh = new MapRefresh();
static MapMake mapMake = Gui.mapMake;
static JPanel panel = Gui.panel;
static Fighting fighting = null;
@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    int x = mapMake.getHeroX();
    int y = mapMake.getHeroY();
    if (e.getKeyCode() == 37 && y > 0){
        mapMake.setDiscovered(x, y-1, 1);
        mapMake.setDiscovered(x, y, 2);
        mapMake.setHeroY(y - 1);
    } else if(e.getKeyCode() == 38 && x > 0){
        mapMake.setDiscovered(x-1, y, 1);
        mapMake.setDiscovered(x, y, 2);
        mapMake.setHeroX(x - 1);
    } else if (e.getKeyCode() == 39 && y < 9){
        mapMake.setDiscovered(x, y+1, 1);
        mapMake.setDiscovered(x, y, 2);
        mapMake.setHeroY(y + 1);
    } else if (e.getKeyCode() == 40 && x < 9){
        mapMake.setDiscovered(x+1, y, 1);
        mapMake.setDiscovered(x, y, 2);
        mapMake.setHeroX(x + 1);
    }
    int z = mapMake.getContent(x, y);
    panel.removeAll();
    System.out.println(e.getKeyCode());
    mapRefresh.MapRefresh();
    panel.validate();
    panel.repaint();

}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {      
}

}
```

I read that the "Try Catch" is slowing it down. Is that it? If so, how can i make it better? Or is this like complete trash?

Keep in mind, that this is our first semester!
Heres also a pastebin copy of it http://pastebin.com/VM1cTvyX

Comment: I have 2 images there ("hall" and "valge"). Just delete them if you want to try the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `MapRefresh()` method is loading those images a vast number of times every update. It would be beneficial to store the image once during the MapRefresh constructor like so:

```
private ImageIcon imageIcon;

public class MapRefresh extends Gui{
static MapMake mapMake = Gui.mapMake;

imageIcon = new ImageIcon(hall = ImageIO.read(new File("C:/hall.jpg")));

//...
}
```

Then when adding to the panel simply use:

```
panel.add(new JLabel(imageIcon));
```

You would repeat this for your other image as well. This should allow you to eliminate the 'try/catch' block with the method which should greatly improve the speed.

Comment: Thanks for the Guide on how to make it ImageIcon!

Answer (score 4):

In your `MapRefresh` class, every time the method `MapRefresh` is called, you are loading an image up to 100 times -- 2 nested loops at 10 iterations each.  That sounds like the source of your slowness.  I would load those two images only once, perhaps in a constructor, and reference them later when needed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
It was indeed the problem.

Answer (score 2):

In my own opinion, the problem comes from the fact that you load the image each time a key is pressed. It makes some read operations on the hard drive which is very slow.

Load your resources at the beginning of the game and use them later.

For the try/catch block, it is slow when you reach the catch block, which forces the JVM to build the stacktrace. Here, you seem to never reach the catch block.